# How to target nested class name inside classNames? React

Tags: css, reactjs, class-names

I need to target nested class inside clasNames.
Check my code first:

```
<div className={containerCss}> 
   <Container> </Container>
</div>
```

And inside CSS

```
.Header { 
  width: 100%;

  .test {
    width: 700px;
  }

  &.test--center {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

I want to add tes class and target Container

if test true to target class test

Answer (score 1):

You should use a ternary operation.

`<div className={isHeader ? "class if it is true" : "class if it is false}></div>`